# How to get parameter from property to script mediator in Integration Studio?

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I want to use the query parameter from the url in the script mediator in Integration Studio. But I can read this parameter as Log. But when I try with the following method in the script mediator, the parameter does not come. Can you help with this

```
<property description="Get EnergyType Of Url" expression="$url:energyType" name="energyType" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

<log description="Logging EnergyType Of Url">
            <property expression="$url:energyType" name="EnergyType"/>
        </log>


<script language="js"><![CDATA[
    var energyType = mc.getProperty('energyType')></script>
```

Comment: Maybe it is a typo when asking, but you are reading `energyType` while saving `EnergyType`, notice the first capital/non capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```xml
<script language="js">
  <![CDATA[
    var energyType = mc.getProperty('query.param.energyType')
    energyType =energyType.toString();
    mc.setProperty('energyType',energyType);
  ]]>
</script>
<property "get-property('energyType')"  name="energyType" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<log level="custom">
  <property expression="get-property('energyType')" name="energyType"/>
</log>
```

Comment: I tried the code you gave.
I am getting the following error while trying to print the value in the Property to an object. And I noticed that it doesn't take the parameter in the log mediator you provided

Error Received:

has no public instance field or method named "toJSON"

`var x = {};
   
            var energyType = mc.getProperty('query.param.energyType');
            energyType = energyType.toString(); 
            mc.setProperty('energyType',energyType);
   x.energyType = energyType;
   
   mc.setPayloadJSON(JSON.stringify(x));`

Comment: why did you remove the mediator script?

Comment: I didint remove script meadiator. I sended script mediator's into